# Access S3 bucket of User Home folder on Appstream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, aws-appstream

Currently we have moved the desktop application on to the appstream successfully .
Appstream provides home folder for every user which is in sync with the S3 bucket .
I wanted to upload files to S3 bucket through another application which can be used by the Appstream user via Home folder .
I wanted to know if there is anyway I can get the list of s3 bucket assigned to Users .
If that is not possible , I wanted to know if there anyway I can mount the S3 bucket on to the Appstream as Home folder .

Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The S3 bucket for all of the users' Home folders is:

> appstream-app-settings-*{region code}*-*{account id without hyphens}*-*{random identifier}*

The individual folders for each user are in

> S3 bucket from above >{Operating System} > {Stack name} > userpool.

And then each folder in the userpool directory is the SHA256 hash of the user's email (as registered in appstream's user pool).

Documentation here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appstream2/latest/developerguide/administer-app-settings-vhds.html#app-persistence-s3-buckets